# Rewrite expression $b^Ty=a^Tx+C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

A really simple question. For four $n$-dimensional vextors $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a scalar $C \in \mathbb{R}$, it is known that $b^Ty=a^Tx+C$. Having another vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can I get the analytical expression of $d^Ty=f(x)$ in terms of $x$? Or is there any way to verify that such an expression is not possible? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible, because of lack of information. Putting a vector $y$ on one side of an equation, means that we need to know an equation for each element of $y$, namely $y_i,i=1,2,...,n$. But the only given information is the inner products, which takes the vectors to a one dimensional space.

Comment: Many thanks! Surely it is impossible to get a definite $y$ as there is only one equation. My original question was not well expressed. In fact, what I need to know is an inner product $d^Ty$ (having another $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$), e.g. $d^Ty=g^Tx+D$. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: well, if I have understood you correctly, I still think that it is not possible, unless d is a multiple of b. However, I am not %100 sure.